# Where does the linker find "-ltermcap" (libtermcap) on macOS (Monterey)?

Tags: macos, ncurses, termcap

I'd like to know where -ltermcap is being "found" on macOS (Monterey) (aka "libtermcap.").

I *know* it's there, somewhere, because this fails to link:

```
cc ../stepit/stepit.o ../readline/libreadline.a testit.o -o testit
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_tputs", referenced from:
      __rl_backspace in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
      __rl_cr in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
      _rl_ding in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
      __rl_standout_on in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
      __rl_standout_off in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
      __rl_enable_meta_key in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
      __rl_disable_meta_key in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
  ...
```

and if I add "-ltermcap", it links (and runs) fine.

Note: I've done "find / -print > allfiles", then "grep libtermcap allfiles" ... no hits.

I've also searched for just "termcap" and (after excluding 'man' pages) found:

```
  3,476 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/termcap.h
     18 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libtermcap.tbd

  3,476 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/termcap.h
     18 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libtermcap.tbd

  3,477 /usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.4/include/ncursesw/termcap.h
     18 /usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.4/include/termcap.h
 14,824 /usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.4/share/man/man3/curs_termcap.3x
 20,106 /usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.4/test/demo_termcap.c
  7,774 /usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.4/test/dots_termcap.c

168,016 /usr/lib/zsh/5.8.1/zsh/termcap.so
```

...nothing like a libtermcap (yeah, the one under .../zsh/... could be, but nothing is point to it / referring to it)

Yes, there are some termcap related files under "Cellar" ... I used brew to install ncurses, but there appears to be no *library* (or any compiled form) of ncurses there.
(Nor do any of my 'env' variables refer to brew or Cellar.)

I'm really puzzled.  Monterey (and a few releases prior) sure made it harder to find things : (

Why do I care?

I have a utility that creates a Makefile for me, and I want to have it check if libtermcap exists on a platform (so I can emit the proper -D flags for some programs that conditionally compile/use routines in libtermcap).  (I compile/run on multiple machines running macOS, Linux, Windows, and HP-UX ... not all machines have libtermcap.)

thanks!

Comment: MacOS doesn't have a separate libtermcap. The functions of libtermcap are in libncurses. There should be a symbolic link libtermcap.dylib -> libncurses.5.4.dylib or whatever. If it's missing you can try to create one. Don't trust me, double-check.

Comment: I've checked for libncurses ... not there, either (well, there is one intended for iOS :)

Answer (score 0):

It is :

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libtermcap.tbd
or 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libtermcap.tbd
```

which is symbolic link to `libncurses.5.4.tbd`

Comment: Unfortunately, .tbd files are ASCII, not code.  In the case of the one mentioned above, I see this in it:  install-name:    '/usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib'

...but that file does not exist.

(I searched all files on the computer for 'libncurses')

thanks.

Comment: @StanSieler tbd=to be done :-(